# CSRF token mismatch in iframe (The Good fix ?)

Tags: laravel-5, iframe, cross-domain, session-cookies, csrf

Form submission in `<iframe>` using laravel throwing `419 CSRF token mismatch` error

I came across couple of solutions but want's a secure one

Please assist which approach is better keeping good security

- Excluding URIs From CSRF Protection https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris
- Extend Cookie Support for SameSite=None, Secure https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/embedding-laravel-form-in-iframe-shows-419-csrf-token-mismatch-error

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This solution is working for me

Yes, you can play with the `config/session.php` `same_site` value.

```
'same_site' => 'lax'
```

to

```
'same_site' => 'none',
```

add in your .env file

```
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true
```